# ¿Cómo puedo pausar un ciclo "for" en cada iteración para preguntar al usuario si continua o se detiene?

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo detener un `for` por cada iteración que haga para consultar al usuario si quiere seguir o no?

Si se sigue, el arreglo sigue pidiendo datos sino el break lo sacaria del bucle.

Comparto el código y la pregunta que me gustaria hacer por cada iteracion del `for`, me refiero a que cuando termine de dar la vuelta 0, pregunte si quiere continuar, si le da que "Sí" continúe con la vuelta 1, y vuelva a preguntar y asi hasta que llegue al final del ciclo.

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Desea llenar un registro mas? NO/SI");
  var respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.ReadKey();
  while (i>0)
  {
    if(respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "NO");
    {
      break;
    }
    if(respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "SI")
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay algunos errores en tu código que impiden que funcione correctamente

1. Las líneas `var respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();` y luego `Console.ReadKey();` piden al usuario ingresar datos 2 veces seguidas
2. Tienes un `while` adentro del `for` cuando usas `break` entonces estarías saliendo del `while` no del `for` ese `while` es innecesario
3. En la línea `if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "NO") ;` tienes un punto y coma `;` al final del if, eso hace que no se ejecute el `break;`

El código funcionando sería así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("Desea llenar un registro mas? NO/SI");
    var respuestaUsuario = Console.ReadLine();

    if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "NO")
    {
        break;
    }
    if (respuestaUsuario.ToUpper() == "SI")
    {
        continue;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Fin");
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el usuario introduce algo distinto a "SI" o a "NO"?

Comment: Muy buena pregunta, el OP no especificó nada al respecto sobre validación así que no es parte de la pregunta pero como comentas debe tomarse en cuenta. Gracias por mencionarlo

Comment: No lo dice explícitamente, pero el código con el bucle while pone de manifiesto esa intención.

Comment: Con el `while` no está validando la respuesta, está comparando el valor de `i` que sea mayor a `0` por lo que supongo que quiso que la respuesta se validara únicamente después de la primera pregunta, de otra forma `respuestaUsuario` se vería involucrada en el `while`. Pero esa es otra pregunta para el OP

Comment: muchas gracias @HeytalePezguato jjeejej parece que no estaba tan lejos de la solucion es que me idea era como hacer que el while generara un buble siempre que i > 0 osea la primera iteracion en 0 lleno luego alli ya entra al while y cuando preguntara si queria continuar pues volvia en la siguiente vuelta a entrar en el while jejeje

Comment: pero si creo que lo que me toca resolver ahora es validar que no se ingrese otra cosa